# how to prove $(-1)\cdot(-1)=1$ based only on the field axioms?

Tags: field-theory, arithmetic

How do I prove $(-1)\cdot(-1)=1$ (or in other words that $-1$ is the multiplicative inverse of itself), based only on the field axioms?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is to get the result of the multiplication $ \cdot $ of $- 1 $ by $-1$. The number $-1$ is the  symmetric of $1$ with respect to addition $ + $. The axioms that relate addition $+$ to multiplication $\cdot$ are *distributivity to the left* and *right distributivity*. Any way to prove this result has to pass through the axiom distributive property which connects the multiplication operation with the addition operation. These equality is a relatively easy exercise.

\begin{align}
(-1)\cdot (-1)= & (-1)\cdot(-1)+\color{red}{0}\\
              = & (-1)\cdot(-1)+\color{red}{[(-1)+1]}\\
              = & (-1)(-1)+\color{red}{\Big(1\cdot(-1)+1\cdot 1\Big)}\\
= & \color{blue}{\Big((-1)(-1)+1\cdot(-1)\Big)}+\color{red}{1\cdot 1} \\
= & \color{blue}{\Big([(-1)+1]\cdot(-1)\Big)}+\color{red}{1} \\
= & \color{blue}{\Big(0\cdot(-1)\Big)}+\color{red}{1} \\
= &\color{blue}{0}+ \color{red}{1}\\
=&1
\end{align}

Comment: wow...thanks!!!

Answer (score 5):

$\textbf{Hint:}$ Think about $(1-1)(1-1)$.

Answer (score 1):

*Principles of Mathematical Analysis - Walter Rudin, 3rd Ed, p7*:

[image]

Comment: Regarding the last equality, -(-(xy))=xy, here is the proof: By addition inverses axiom, -x+x=0. Replace x by -x. This gives -(-(x))=x

Comment: By the way you will still have to prove $0 \cdot y = 0$, this shouldn't be difficult though.

Comment: Also still need to prove that ax+b=0 has one and only solution but I know how to prove these two, so that's really good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

$(-1) \cdot (-1)=(-1) \cdot (-1)+(-1) \cdot (1)-(-1) \cdot 1=(-1) \cdot (-1+1)-(-1)=1.$

Answer (score 0):

$-1\cdot\text{sth.}=\text{additive inverse of sth.}$,thus $-1\cdot(-1)=1$, as $1$ is the additive inverse of $-1$.

Comment: You have to prove that $-1 \cdot x = -x$...

Comment: $0 = 0\cdot x = (1+(-1))\cdot x = 1\cdot x + (-1)\cdot x = x + (-1)\cdot x \implies (-1)\cdot x = -x$.